# Authentication using Google Oauth via Service Stack is not setting the session aftre redirecting back from google

Tags: servicestack, google-oauth

Authentication using Google Oauth via Service Stack is not setting the session aftre redirecting back from google. Here are my code snippets.

AppHost:

```
        Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new CustomuserSession(), new IAuthProvider[]
        {
            new CustomCredentialsAuthProvider(container.Resolve<IAuthentication>()),
            new GoogleOAuth2Provider(appSettings), //Sign-in with Google OpenId
        }));
```

Web.config:

```
<add key="oauth.CallbackUrl" value="http://localhost:57162/Home" />
<add key="oauth.RedirectUrl" value="http://localhost:57162/auth/googleoauth" />
<add key="oauth.GoogleOAuth.ConsumerKey" value="MyConsumerKey"/>
<add key="oauth.GoogleOAuth.ConsumerSecret" value="MyConsumerSecret"/>
```

The authentication happens fine but once it redirects back to my application, the session info is not set and hence anr service calls still returns a status code of "403:Unauthorized". The "OnAuthenticated" method inside my custom session object is not being called at all. Am I missing something?

Update 1:

Here is my custom session object with the "OnAuthenticated" method. And I am calling the base.OnAuthenticated inside it. But the probkem is the custom session object's OnAuthenticated method itself is not being hit which means that something is happening before the authentication happens or its not happening properly which is what Im not able to figure out. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
   public class CustomUserSession : AuthUserSession
   {
    private readonly IAuthentication _authentication;
    private const string DefaultRedirect = "Home";
    public UserDetails UserDetails { get; set; }

    public CustomUserSession(IAuthentication authentication)
    {
        _authentication = authentication; 
    }

    public override void OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, IAuthTokens tokens, Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
    {
        var redirectUrl = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(authService.Request.UrlReferrer.Query)["redirect"] ?? DefaultRedirect;        
        foreach (var authToken in session.ProviderOAuthAccess)
        {
            UserDetails = _authentication.Authenticate(authToken.UserId);
            if (authToken.Provider == GoogleOAuth2Provider.Name)
            {
                UserDetails.UserId = authToken.UserId;
                UserDetails.FirstName = authToken.FirstName;
                UserDetails.LastName = authToken.LastName;
                UserDetails.Email = authToken.Email;
            }
            authService.SaveSession(session);          
        }
        base.OnAuthenticated(authService, session, tokens, authInfo);
        session.ReferrerUrl = authService.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri.Replace(authService.Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery, redirectUrl);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could someone please let me know if Im missing something here as it would be really helpful. if you need any more info to be posted, please do let me know Thanks.

Comment: I would post your custom Session and OnAuthenticated method. Sounds like you might not be calling the base.OnAuthenticated

Answer (score 1):

From the code you have provided, you aren't using your `CustomUserSession` with your `AuthFeature`.

Your session factory, the first argument of the `AuthFeature`, should be returning an instance of your `CustomUserSession`.

`Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new CustomUserSession(), new IAuthProvider[]
{
    new CustomCredentialsAuthProvider(container.Resolve<IAuthentication>()),
    new GoogleOAuth2Provider(appSettings), //Sign-in with Google OpenId
}));`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry my bad.. Its actually CustomuserSession. I tried in between to try the same code out with a much simpler class which I had named "Session" but forgot to remove it when i posted the question. But even with that the issue was persisting. Updated the question as well.

Comment: You might want to put together a project, cause there are still issues with the code in your question, for eg, the CustomUsersession has a single constructor taking an 'IAuthentication' (which I am assuming is your own interface), which is not reflected in the code snippet above. Hard to isolate a problem without an accurate picture of what's going on. If you could put together a project illustrating the issue I can take a look. Cheers.